# Сортировка массива строк в алфавитном порядке

Tags: c, сортировка

В общем задание такое. Перемещая указатель, рассортировать введенный с клавиатуры массив строк в алфавитном порядке. Ввод, сортировку и вывод массива выполнить в отдельных функциях. Стандартные функции работы со строками не использовать. Вот код, но программа почему-то падает. Объясните,пожалуйста, что я сделал не так.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#define N 100
#define M 30

 void vvod(int n, int i, char a[i]);
 void sor(int n, int i, char a[i]);
 void print(int n, int i, char a[i]);

 int main(int argc, char* argv[])/*Главная функция*/
 {
    char a[N][M];
    int n, i;

    setlocale(LC_ALL,".1251");
    printf("Введите количество слов: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("Введите слова: ");
    vvod(n, i, a[i]);/*Функция ввода*/
    sor(n, i, a[i]);/*Функция сортировки*/
    print(n, i, a[i]);/*Функция вывода*/

    return 0;
 }

void vvod(int n, int i, char a[i])/*Функция ввода*/
 {
    for (i=0; i<n-1; i++)
       scanf("%s", &a[i]);
       return vvod( n, i, a[i]);
 }

void sor(int n, int i, char a[i])/*Функция сортировки*/
{
 for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       for(int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {
           if(a[j] > a[j+1]) {
              int tmp = a[j];
              a[j] = a[j+1];
              a[j+1] = tmp;
           }
        }
    }
    return sor(n, i, a[i]);
}
void print(int n, int i, char a[i])/*Функция вывода*/
 {
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
       printf("%s\n", a[i]);
    return print(n, i, a[i]);
 }
```

Comment: >программа почему-то падает

Use The Debugger, Luke!

Comment: помедитируйте над функцией vvod. Она возвращает что то странное.

другие функции в принципе тоже.

Comment: Очень интересная функция "sor". Жутко рекурсивная. "Как Вы яхту назовёте, так она и поплывёт" (c) к. Врунгель. 

Да и вообще непонятно, что она должна делать, эта функция-сор. Да и другие функции тоже. Ну не должно быть там параметра `char a[i]`. Он скорее должен быть `char *a[]` или `char **a`

Comment: Для начала объясните, какой компилятор умудрился скомпилировать конструкции вроде 
    
    void vvod(int n, int i, char a[i]);

Что это вообще такое? Как, зачем и почему вы используете индексацию при объявлении параметров функции?

Comment: Все просто, я не могу в функции. Я их плохо понимаю.

Comment: В таком случае, стоит для начала почитать какие-нибудь учебники, уяснить для себя, что такое функции, как их объявляют и используют. То что вы сейчас выложили - жуткая ересь, которая во-первых, не должна компилироваться вообще, а во-вторых, должна упасть при вызове любой из ваших функций с переполнением стека (почитайте про рекурсию, вы её здесь используете, хотя она здесь не нужна).

Comment: А в какой момент происходит выход из рекурсии? Ведь в каждой функции есть условие входа в цикл, после которого, неважно зашло в него или нет, функция вызывает саму себя, а возврата обратно нет.